# Edit configuration values in magento (magento extension)

Tags: magento

I've created a Magento extension which uses the system.xml file in my /etc/ dir (for my module) to add fields to my configuration. Magento 1.5 is my target system at the moment, but I also intend to extend compatibility to 1.4 and .16

```
<merchantid translate="label">
      <label>Merchant ID</label>
      <frontend_type>text</frontend_type>
      <sort_order>20</sort_order>
      <show_in_default>1</show_in_default>
      <show_in_website>1</show_in_website>
      <show_in_store>0</show_in_store>
</merchantid>
```

I'm trying to populate the value of this field during runtime. Currently, I am running this inside my plugin: `Mage::getStoreConfig('payment/mymerchant/merchantid');` which returns the value populated in the field.

I need to be able to update this field programatically, I tried this:

```
 $installer = new Mage_Core_Model_Resource_Setup();
                $installer->startSetup();
                $installer->setConfigData("payment/mymerchant/merchantid", "TEST");
                $installer->endSetup();
```

But had no success. I am having trouble googling the problem too because most results don't appear relevant.

Does anyone have anyidea how I can set these values?

Comment: Are you looking for default values for these configurations?  Or does the value need to be different depending on other factors?

Comment: it needs to be different depending on the situation. How does one set the default value anyway?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If you're looking for default values you can do:

```
<config>
...
    <default>
        <payment>
            <ezimerchant>
                <merchantid>TEST</merchantid>
            </ezimerchant>
        </payment>
    </default>
</config>
```

If you are really looking for a programmatic solution you can do the following:

```
$configModel = Mage::getModel('core/config');
$configModel->saveConfig('payment/ezimerchant/merchantid','TEST');
```

The third parameter is what cope to save it, 'default', 'website', 'store'.  The fourth parameter defines which Website ID or Store ID you want to save it with.

Edit:  You must either disable cache when doing this or refresh/flush cache afterwards for the change to take effect.

Comment: Great. You know what? the $installer code I used actually does work, you just have to refresh twice because if you do a set and then a get in magento it will ignore the DB and read from memory. +1 anyway as this looks good. will use in the future. Thanks

Comment: It's not that the DB settings are ignored, it's just that the configuration is already parsed into memory for the current execution scope. This can be overcome by setting both config XML and the install script data, or by explicitly calling `loadDb()` on the  config object at the end of the setup script.